# Why is this python list storing only the last input elements

Tags: list, input, python-3.8

Please explain the following behavior

```
import sys
input=sys.stdin.readline

for _ in range(int(input())):
    n=int(input())
    m=int(input())
    vertices=[[0, 0]]*n
    edges=[[0, 0, 0]]*m
    for i in range(m):
        edges[i][0], edges[i][1], edges[i][2]=list(map(int, input().split()))
    for i in range(m):
        print(edges[i][0], edges[i][1], edges[i][2])
```

When the following input is fed into the program:

```
1
5
7
1 2 1
2 3 2
2 4 6
5 2 1
5 1 3
4 5 2
3 4 3
```

This output is being produced:

```
3 4 3
3 4 3
3 4 3
3 4 3
3 4 3
3 4 3
3 4 3
```

Why is only the last inputs are being stored in all of the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this interpreter session:

```
>>> a = [[0,0,0]] * 5
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[0][0] = 1
>>> a
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

This is actually a common pitfall in Python. The code translates to something like this

```
inner = [0, 0, 0]
a = [inner, inner, inner, inner, inner]
```

This way of writing makes it clearer that you actually create a list where **all entries point to the same object (`inner`)**.

One way to fix this is to use a list comprehension, this way a new inner list will be created for each list entry:

```
vertices=[[0, 0] for _ in range(n)]
edges=[[0, 0, 0] for _ in range(m)]
```

Another fix would be using numpy and declaring a 2D matrix using `numpy.zeros(n, 2)`. Numpy is generally useful for math/numerics-intensive applications.